# Keep UIButton Selected/Highlighted after touch

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift

I'd like my button to remain highlighted after the user taps it. If the user taps the button again I'd like it to become de-selected/unhighlighted. I'm not sure how to go about doing this in swift. I'm currently setting the button highlight image and selected image to the same .png using interface builder.

When I run the app and tap the button, it changes to my highlight image for as long as my finger remains on the button.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use below code
 declare `isHighLighted` as instance variable

```
//write this in your class
 var isHighLighted:Bool = false


override func viewDidLoad() {

    let button  = UIButton(type: .system)

    button.setTitle("Your title", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44)

    self.view.addSubview(button as UIView)

    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

}

func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

        if isHighLighted == false{
            sender.highlighted = true;
            isHighLighted = true
        }else{
            sender.highlighted = false;
            isHighLighted = false
        }
     });
}
```

I would recomend to use `selected` state instead of `highlighted` the below code demonstarate with selected state

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    let button  = UIButton(type: .system)

    button.setTitle("Your title", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44)

    self.view.addSubview(button as UIView)
    //set normal image 
    button.setImage(normalImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    //set highlighted image 
    button.setImage(selectedImage, forState: UIControlState.Selected)

    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

}

func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton)
{
      sender.selected = !sender.selected;
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing where you declared "isHighLigthed" in the code. I see where you are checking value of "isHighLighted", but not where you actually declare it

Comment: declare it after `class Abc{` line `var isHighLighted:Bool = false`.This will work perfect

Comment: @user3822654 you van also use selected state as that is more used for toggling behaviour.You need to set two images one for `normalState` other for `selectedState`.Hope this helps

Comment: That is not a problem to use button as InterfaceBuilder but you should decare `isHighLighted` in class.Global variables are not good.Do you getting any problem if declaring in class??

Comment: I declared "isHighLighted" at the top of my main swift document (my model?). The way I understand it, this variable will now be seen as a global variable and will be used as you suggested:

`import Foundation
import UIKit

var isHighLighted = false`

I didn't use the first bit of code you provided to set up my button, but instead used interface builder and it worked great.

The second option using the selected state also works and is much simpler! Can you explain how it works? I don't understand the "!" syntax (an optional?) placed before "sender.selected"

Comment: `!sender.selected` is not optional it is `not` operator.It reverse the value.for eg if `aBool` has `true` than `!aBool` returns `false` and if your button is not selected than `sender.selected = !sender.selected;` this makes sender ie. button `selected`

Comment: I'm unsure what class to include the variable in. Currently we are defining button states and actions in the view controller, so I don't know what class to place the variable. I only have one class defined in my app which is called later when a different button is tapped.

Comment: Your example with highlighted works with only one Button, can you please update your answer to work for an Array of Buttons :-))

Answer (score 6):

```
func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // "button" is a property

    if button.isSelected {
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "filled-heart"), for: .normal)
        button.isSelected = false
    }else {
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "empty-heart"), for: .selected)
        button.isSelected = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
func highlightButton(button: UIButton) {
       button.highlighted = true
}

@IBAction func touched(sender: UIButton) {
    let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.0, target: self, selector: Selector("highlightButton(sender)"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example in Swift?

Comment: Oh sorry didn't know that you want it in Swift

Comment: Now when I tap my button, the app crashes and Xcode highlights the first line in my AppDelegate with a note "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

Answer (score 0):

this one worked fine for me!

```
func buttonColorChanger(sender :  UIButton )  {

    if button.isSelected == false
    {

        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
        print("selected")

        button.setTitle("selected", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
         button.isSelected = true
    }else{

        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        print("unselected")
        button.isSelected = false

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5:**

```
@IBAction func toggleButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
}
```