# how add barbuttonitem highlighted in start app?(Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, toolbar

I want whenever pressed one of barbuttonitems be highlighted & whenever i pressed the other first one goes to normal, and second be highlighted & when i start app first one be highlighted as default..

[image]

Comment: You'll probably to do that in your `viewDidLoad`. In methods tied to your other buttons, you'll want to turn it off. Another thought might be to use a `UISegmentedControl`. This post should point you in the right direction.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844865/keep-uibutton-selected-highlighted-after-touch-in-swift

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a `UITabBar`. [UITabBar Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBar_Class/index.html)

Comment: yes, something like UITabBar but in UITabBar you can,t use @IBAction, I use UIBarButtonItem to change photos on UIImageVIew

Comment: @rezamagnet You can implement the `UITabBar`'s delegate, then you know which item is selected by the user.

Comment: @Bannings please check my codes **[link](http://s21.postimg.org/4g5icv07r/Screen_Shot_1394_04_07_at_18_02_14.png)**how can i do this by UITabBar to change photos