# Keep glow effect of shows​Touch​When​Highlighted after the user lifts their finger from the button

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

So I have set `shows​Touch​When​Highlighted` to true for a button and the button glows when I pressed it. However, I want to figure out how to keep it glowing after the user lifts their finger off the button. Basically, to let the user know the button is highlighted. Thanks!

Comment: when touched copy the style of button to a variable, then in event where touch is gone apply it back again.

Comment: okay that makes sense but how do you copy the style?

Comment: var touchedstyle=document.getElementById(<buttonelementid>).style.color etc will copy those individual styles. so u need to copy the style property which makes it glow

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844865/keep-uibutton-selected-highlighted-after-touch-in-swift

Comment: @Rico there is no such thing as  `getElementById`!

Comment: ok, i am sorry i was thinking it was javascript n html ok

Comment: there are buttons everywhere, even on shirt, how was i supposed to know which language he coding it :P

Comment: @Rico you look at tags

Comment: oh i see, i will remember it next time, this site is so complicated to use :/ but my answer was right no? copy the style in the pressed state and then apply it again when unpressed.

Answer (score 0):

Place this in a `@IBAction` in which the button is pressed (where button is your `UIButton`

```
self.button.isHighlighted = !self.button.isHighlighted
```

Comment: UIButton has no member variable of selected. it does have a variable of isSelected but that still doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, forgot that you were using `showsTouchWhenHighlighted`. See the edit